# Is .net-core 2.2 compatible with windows server 2008 sp2?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, asp.net-core, .net-core

Upon trying to install .net core 2.2 (dotnet-hosting-2.2.5-win.exe 32-bit) the below error is generated:

> Error 0x80070001: Process returned error: 0x1 Error 0x80070001: Failed
>   to execute EXE package. Error 0x80070001: Failed to configure
>   per-machine EXE package. Applied execute package: DotNetRedistLts_x86,
>   result: 0x80070001, restart: None Error 0x80070001: Failed to execute
>   EXE package.

Comment: [This would suggest that yes, it's compatible](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/release-notes/2.2/2.2-supported-os.md)

Comment: Have you tried to install  .NET Core Installer X86 from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/2.0 ?

Comment: Are you using a Windows 2008 SP2 x86 machine or x64?

Comment: It's a x86 machine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the .NET Core SDK from the Microsoft website? If not then I think that this may be the reason for the error. https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download

Comment: Downloaded from the same URL

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is `WINDOWS SERVER 2008 Version` , into documentation says it is compatible with `Windows Server 2008 R2 sp1+`. Maybe you have Standard version `Windows Server 2008 (not R2)`?